# How do I remove the x-axis values that I do not need from each plot?

Tags: r

I have a dataset of 'Sites' found across China and what 'Province' they are found in. Using R, I have some code that then separates those found in the North or the South of China based on the 'Sites' latitude. I then want to display how many 'Sites' are found in each 'Province' but separated into two plots next to each other - one for the North and one for the South.

The problem I am having is that both plots show ALL of the 'Provinces' - [see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlZF4.png)

```
main_data <- read_excel("sample_data_for_r_test.xlsx")

### Add a new variable 'china_region' that splits sites into north and south based on latitude ###

main_data_r <-
main_data %>%
  mutate(china_region = ifelse(Latitude >= 32,
                               "North",
                               "South"))

### How many bone specimens per Province? ###

tally_per_province <- 
  main_data_r %>% 
  group_by(Province, china_region) %>% 
  tally()

ggplot(tally_per_province) +
  aes(reorder(Province, n),
      n) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap( ~ china_region) +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(angle = 90)) +
  labs(x = "Province", 
       y = "Count of specimens")
```

What would be the best way of removing the repeated 'Province' values from the x-axis?

[Sample data here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbe5l6zkg196v95/sample%20data%20for%20r%20test.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Try with `facet_wrap( ~ china_region, scales = "free_x")`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much.